# Table layout for a php product catalogue

Tags: php, html-table, shopping-cart

I've created a product catalogue in PHP, I want the products to come up as a table like in a grid, so it has 3 products on one row side by side, then carries on underneath and so on. I've got it so the products repeat horizontally, I just don't know how to make it automatically start a new line after three products..

Here's my code currently:

```
<?php # Script 17.5 - browse_prints.php
// This page displays the available prints (products).

// Set the page title and include the HTML header:
$page_title = 'Browse the Films';

require_once ('mysqli_connect.php');

// Default query for this page:
$q = "SELECT image_name, genre.genre_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', genre_name) AS genre, film_name, price, platform, description, film_id, image_name FROM genre, film WHERE genre.genre_id = film.genre_id AND film.platform = 'DVD' ORDER BY genre.genre_name ASC, film.film_name ASC ";

// Are we looking at a particular genre?
if (isset($_GET['gid']) && is_numeric($_GET['gid']) ) {
$gid = (int) $_GET['gid'];
if ($gid > 0) { // Overwrite the query:
    $q = "SELECT image_name, genre.genre_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', genre_name) AS genre, film_name, price, description, film_id, image_name FROM genre, film WHERE genre.genre_id = film.genre_id AND film.genre_id = $gid AND film.platform = 'DVD' ORDER BY film.film_name";
}
}



// Create the table head:
echo '<table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="center">
<tr>
    <td align="left" width="50%"><b>Film Name</b></td>
    <td align="right" width="50%"><b>Price</b></td>
</tr><tr>';


// Display all the prints, linked to URLs:
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

// Display each record:
//image
$image_name = $row['image_name'];
echo "
    <td><a href=\"view_print.php?fid={$row['film_id']}\">{$row['film_name']}<br><br>
    <img src=uploads/$image_name.jpg><br>
    <br>&#163;{$row['price']}</td>
";


} // End of while loop.

echo '</tr></table>';
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

div are better solutions than tables.
But if you want to do that, add a counter.

```
// Create the table head:
echo '<table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="center">
<tr>
    <td align="left" width="50%"><b>Film Name</b></td>
    <td align="right" width="50%"><b>Price</b></td>
</tr>';

$row_count = 0:
// Display all the prints, linked to URLs:
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$row_count++;
if ($row_count==1) echo "<tr>";
// Display each record:
//image
$image_name = $row['image_name'];
echo "
    <td><a href=\"view_print.php?fid={$row['film_id']}\">{$row['film_name']}<br><br>
    <img src=uploads/$image_name.jpg><br>
    <br>&#163;{$row['price']}</td>
";
    if ($row_count==3) {
         echo "</tr>";
         $row_count=0;
    }
} // End of while loop.

if ($row_count>0) echo "</tr>";
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an index variable inside the loop:

```
$i = 0;
while ...
{
   // other code...

   $i++;
   if ($i % 3 == 0) { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
<table>
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
        if($i%3==0){
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo "<td>Product - ".$i."<td/>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

**Output**

```
Product - 0     Product - 1     Product - 2 
Product - 3     Product - 4     Product - 5 
Product - 6     Product - 7     Product - 8 
Product - 9     Product - 10        Product - 11
```